# Secure Bearer Token using Encryption algorithm

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, encryption, oauth

In a WebApi project using Identity framework and Owin, authorization & authentication is working fine. Next step is I want to make my bearer token more secure and need to implement Encryption & Decryption of bearer tokens.

The encrypted string will be decrypted in Actionfilter before validation. Is there any recommended way of doing this? I tried multiple implementation of AES & DES but i am trying to implement any recommended way of doing it.

AES Implementation:

```
static byte[] Encrypt(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {  
        byte[] encrypted;  
        // Create a new AesManaged.    
        using(AesManaged aes = new AesManaged()) {  
            // Create encryptor    
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV);  
            // Create MemoryStream    
            using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {  
                // Create crypto stream using the CryptoStream class. This class is the key to encryption    
                // and encrypts and decrypts data from any given stream. In this case, we will pass a memory stream    
                // to encrypt    
                using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {  
                    // Create StreamWriter and write data to a stream    
                    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))  
                    sw.Write(plainText);  
                    encrypted = ms.ToArray();  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        // Return encrypted data    
        return encrypted;  
    }  
    static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {  
        string plaintext = null;  
        // Create AesManaged    
        using(AesManaged aes = new AesManaged()) {  
            // Create a decryptor    
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV);  
            // Create the streams used for decryption.    
            using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) {  
                // Create crypto stream    
                using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {  
                    // Read crypto stream    
                    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs))  
                    plaintext = reader.ReadToEnd();  
                }  
            }  
        }  
        return plaintext;  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The recommended way is not to do this. There should not be a reason to do this.

Keep in mind the reason why OAuth/OpenID exist. The whole point is decentralized authentication. That's why these tokens are encoded base64. That way any client can use this third party to identify of the user. (Note that I did not write "authorize") Obviously the user should give consent, or the identity provider denies access based. (by validating the redirect url, or not knowing the client)

Also note the difference between openId and OAuth. Claims are an openID concept. Also the concept of Json webtokens come from OpenID (not OAuth). OAuth has no readable bearer tokens. Again: Note the purpose of the two different protocols. I tried to explain these protocols here: https://medium.com/@abstarreveld/oauth-and-openid-explained-with-real-life-examples-bf40daa8049f

For your question: Do not encrypt the bearer tokens. You could consider using reference tokens instead of jwt tokens. That way it becomes a lot harder to read the contents of these tokens. If you really want the tokens to be unreadable, create your own owin implementation of JUST OAUTH. Use scopes instead of claims there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The project is very confidential and there will be no other third parties involved. Only one client and one server. The point of using scopes is great idea and we will try but encrypting token is what we need right now. We want our token to be unreadable to any one else no matter what.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using json web tokens, right? If so: Why no switching to reference tokens? Those are unreadable (unless you have the secret and the introspection endpoint of course....)

Comment: I am not using JWT tokens. I am using Defualt OWIN authentication which is OAuth probably.

Comment: Ah.. I see... So you're using plain OAuth then... As I described in my article, the difference between OAuth and OpenID is that OpenID introduced the concept of claims and json web tokens (which should be readable).  This is important because the claimsidentity object you're probably looking at is an implementation of OpenID instead of OAuth.

Oauth uses scopes instead which aren't readable. Oauth doesn't dictate if an accesstoken should be readable whatsoever.. To achieve that you'll have to build your own owin implementation.

Comment: The point is, though.. That writing your own implementation is going to be a lot harder, because OpenID (and readable stuff with it) is strongly embedded in the .net framework. Going this direction is - in my opinion - ambitious..

Comment: I am not using OpenID for now. I have my own custom OWIN implementation.  tokens are signed using private key on server side, if on the client side someone maliciously changes the token and tries to access some resource, your server will detect this when malicious token is sent to the server. this is done out of the box i think..

Comment: What I would personally do is create an OpenID implementation, and make sure I would not be sending any meaningfull contents across the wire at al. A way to achieve that is by using reference tokens. In that case the bearer token becomes completely meaningless and unreadable. Yet no encryption is needed to achieve that. You can choose to implement that yourself, but i'd recommend to implement Identity Server and configure it to use reference tokens.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/